# How to check if User is Signed In in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

Hy here everyone. I am new to flutter and i want to check if User is SignedIn. If so the user navigate to HomeScreen else SplashScreen.

Here is my main.dart

```
void main() async{
  runApp(MyApp());
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
String initRoute;
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

getUser(){
  
  if (user != null) {
  initRoute = MainScreen.routeName;
} else {
  initRoute = SplashScreen.routeName;
}
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Instant Tasker',
      theme: theme(),
      initialRoute: initRoute,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code of your. Here I have check your login process.After checking the login code I will be able to solve your issue

Comment: This is the complete code of main.dart

Comment: Where did you find getUSer() func? where did you import these ?? I need to see or else I wont be able to help

Comment: i didn't import. The getUser() function is just created there

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at this youtube playlist to learn more about using firebase in flutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA3NWDBPZ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC

Answer (score 2):

The proper way that I see is through the Firebase plugin, here is how it looks like.

in main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) => print(value));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

String userData() {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    return uid;
  }
```

if a user is logged in it will return  uid(String) otherwise null

Comment: ``` E/flutter (27826): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()```

Comment: you need to call Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: hahah lol. you just copied my solution. better work hard

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the best way to identify if a user is already signed in or not is via using Shared Preferences.

Just add [this](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

Every time a user logs in a particular device you can save some value as a key value pair in the phone's storage using Shared Preferences.

Next time whenever a user opens the app you can just check if any value is available in the shared preferences. If so then open the Home Screen else open the Splash Screen.

This is by far the cleanest solution.

You can read more about shared Preferences [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127).

If you still need a sample code. Drop a comment and I will edit the answer.

Thanks

Comment: I used shared prefences as mentioned in one of stackoverflow post but it moved to splash screen and thats it nothing was working not even the button. Can you please explain how should i used it.

Answer (score 0):

you should right function getuser with return statement of widget that contains return Statement of mainScreen if user signed in or else splashscreen and use this function in home:

```
 Widget  getUser(){

 if (user != null) {
 mainScreen();
 } else {
 splashScreen();
 }
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Instant Tasker',
  theme: theme(),
  home:getUser(),
 );
  }
 }
```

Comment: it shows No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()....... But i used Firebase.initalizeApp() at main

Answer (score -1):

Thank you every one i solved my problem. Everyone on stackoverflow was providing complex solutions but still didn't solve the problem. The mistake everyone was making is they were using Firebase before the 'FirebaseApp initialize'. So i simply call the runApp when the FirebaseApp is initialized.cHere is my code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Instant Tasker',
      theme: theme(),
      initialRoute: user != null ? MainScreen.routeName : SplashScreen.routeName,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```